# Always scroll to the end of a Scrollable Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am writing a simple Angular Chat Box, which contains a scrollable table and an input field. The input is placed at the end. Everytime I enter a message, the table scroll doesn't move. I am tring to focus it to the last row of the table. Here is my code so far :

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="msg in chatList ">
            <td><strong>{{ msg.sender}} : </strong>
            </td>
            <td>{{msg.message}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="text " ng-model="message " class="form-control " placeholder="Enter a Message ">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-s " ng-hide="true " type="submit ">Submit</button>
```

Comment: How are you trying to scroll the table? Can you post that code or CSS aswell?

Comment: You can add a angular filter to your repeat to sort in the order you want.  Say descending so your old posts get pushed down.  Check out styles here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvRXaM

Comment: @Karthik : http://jsfiddle.net/98zd6k7t/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned without the rest of your HTML and CSS you use to actually set up the scrolling, this is rather difficult to answer.

Judging by your use of type="submit" this chat triggers on a form submit, I added a directive to the form that can target an element to bring to the bottom scroll position on a 'chat'. You could in theory hook this into anything if you change the event handler although remember to remove it upon destroy.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/11961/

```
.directive("fixBottom", function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var scrollBot = function(){                
                var target = document.getElementById(attrs.fixBottom);
                target.scrollTop = target.scrollHeight;
            };

            element[0].addEventListener("submit", scrollBot);

            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                 element[0].removeEventListener("submit", scrollBot);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi Ash, Now I want to connect my app to a server back-end, so that its real-time. Can you let me know how I should proceed further !

Comment: Hi Karthik. So you mean when the chat recieves a message, it scrolls to the bottom again? There's a few ways you could do it. Personally I would put the chat logic inside a service and use $broadcast on the $rootscope whenever a message is received. You can then do $on on the $rootscope to let the fixBottom directive react accordingly. Does that make sense? I could draft something up if not

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your html this may not be exactly what you need but how about just scrolling to the input box position as the last `TR` should be just above that?

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#IDOfTheInput").offset().top
}, 2000);
```